# Is this a decent way of writing a start-stop-daemon script?

Tags: bash

This is the first time I've written a start-stop-daemon script, so I would love some feedback. :) The goal is to have it start late, when the network and everything is ready. I also have 2 other start-stop-daemons that depend on this once being started before they launch and are nearly identical.

```
#! /bin/sh
# chkconfig 345 85 60
# description: startup script for foo
# processname: foo

NAME=foo
DIR=/etc/foo/services
EXEC=foo.py
PID_FILE=/var/run/foo.pid
IEXE=/etc/init.d/foo
RUN_AS=root

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          foo
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 2 3 6
# Description:       Starts the foo service
### END INIT INFO

if [ ! -f $DIR/$EXEC ]
then
        echo "$DIR/$EXEC not found."
        exit
fi

case "$1" in
  start)
        echo -n "Starting $NAME"
    cd $DIR
    start-stop-daemon -d $DIR --start --background --pidfile $PID_FILE --make-pidfile --exec $EXEC --quiet
        echo "$NAME are now running."
        ;;
  stop)
    echo -n "Stopping $NAME"
        kill -TERM `cat $PID_FILE`
    rm $PID_FILE
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;
  force-reload|restart)
        $0 stop
        $0 start
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Use: /etc/init.d/$NAME {start|stop|restart|force-reload}"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: Awesome script. I see you activated the --background flag. In fact, this ties into my interest on this question (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2841/4307). I plan on making a Daemon too.

Comment: You might want to look on Ubuntu with the /etc/init.d/skeleton sample script, and then edit that. That way, you get the status command, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Probably, you also may implement `condrestart`:

> The condrestart (conditional restart) option only starts the daemon if it is currently running.
>   This option is useful for scripts, because it does not start the daemon if it is not running.

Quote from [question about `condrestart` at LinuxQuestions](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/condrestart-531071/)